# {"status":400,"message":"missing client id"} response when using node-fetch

Tags: javascript, node.js, twitch, node-fetch, twitch-api

I am trying to get an oauth token from Twitch, and with this code:

```
import dotenv from 'dotenv';
dotenv.config();
import fetch from 'node-fetch';

let creds = {
        client_id:process.env.CLIENT_ID,
        client_secret:process.env.CLIENT_SECRET,
        grant_type:"client_credentials"
};

let request = {
    method:'POST',
    header:{ "Content-Type": "application/json" },
    body:creds
};
console.log(request);

fetch(process.env.AUTH_URL,request)
    .then (res => res.text())
    .then (text => console.log(text))
```

With my secret and client id where appropriate.  However it keeps returning:

```
{"status":400,"message":"missing client id"}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Please verify there is something in: `console.log(process.env.CLIENT_ID)`. If yes, run your program with the env variable `NODE_DEBUG=http` to see the request made.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to stringify the body before sending it and `headers` instead of `header`.

```js
let request = {
    method:'POST',
    headers:{ "Content-Type": "application/json" },
    body:JSON.stringify(creds)
};
```

Also, maybe use `res.json()` instead because the return data maybe `json`.

```js
fetch(process.env.AUTH_URL,request)
    .then (res => res.json())
    .then (text => console.log(text))
```

Comment: got the same error as before.

Comment: @user992286, `headers` instead of `header`. See updates.